# Chance of Winning In Tic Tac Toe

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I'm sure everyone knows how to play the game of tic-tac-toe.

I have just been wondering what's the probability of winning if one player started his or her move by putting his mark in the middle?

Comment: If the opponent plays optimally, the chance of winning is $0$ for either player.

Comment: This is not related to "analysis" at all ...

Comment: http://xkcd.com/832/

Comment: You didn't say whether the two players alternate turns or not.  If they don't necessarily alternate, then the probability that the center player will win is $\frac{41}{64} = 64.0625\%$. Reference: [A. Lazarus, D. Loeb, J. Propp, W. Stromquist, and D. Ullman, Combinatorial
games under auction play, Games Econom. Behav. 27 (1999),  229-264](http://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/auction-based-tic-tac-toe-solution/)

Answer (score 10):

If the other player plays properly, zero.  The game is known to be a draw.  If you want to assume random play by both sides, you could make a tree and calculate it.  There are only two responses to a center opening-a corner or a side, but then more branches to the tree after that because the symmetry is broken.

Answer (score 4):

I believe there is always a way to end the game in a tie, so the chance of winning would be zero. (assuming the opponent knew what move to make in response to your move)

This might be relevant: http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~jorgev/cs106/ttt.pdf

Answer (score 4):

It is always random. Depending on the skill of the player, it may be 0/100 or 100/0. Putting the X in the middle doesn't necessarily mean that you will have a higher chance of winning. In fact I've seen my fair share of people who put their X (if they go first) in the corner or on the sides.